# AWS CodeDeploy: stuck on install step

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-code-deploy

I'm running through [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-ecs-ecr-codedeploy.html) tutorial to create a deployment pipeline with my custom **.net**-based docker image.
But when I start a deployment, it's stuck on **install** phase, so I have to stop it manually:
[image]

After that I get a couple of running tasks with different task definitions (note :1 and :4, 'cause I've tried to run deployment 4 times by now):
[image]

They also change their state **RUNNING->PROVISIONING->PENDING** all the time. And the list of stopped tasks grows:
[image]

Q:
So, how to hunt down the issue with CodeDeploy? Why It's running forever?

**UPDATE:**
It is connected to health checks.

**UPDATE:**
I'm getting this:

```
(service dataapi-dev-service, taskSet ecs-svc/9223370487815385540) (port 80) is unhealthy in target-group dataapi-dev-tg1 due to (reason Health checks failed with these codes: [404]).
```

Don't quite understand, why is it failing for newly created container, 'cause the original one passes health-check.

Comment: @MatthewSainsbury, could you please help me?

Comment: Could you explain how you obtained this log? I am following the same tutorial and got the same problem... Also I do not understand how to apply the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the ECS task is running, ELB (Elastic Load Balancer) will constantly do healthchecking the container as you config in the target group to check if the container is still responding.

From your debug message, the container (api) responded the healthcheck path with 404.

I suggest you config the healhcheck path in target group `dataapi-dev-tg1`.

Comment: True. Also I must note, that even when I fixed health check for `dataapi-dev-tg1`, the  deployment failed for `dataapi-dev-tg2` with the same message. Mess...

Comment: How can I obtain the logs from the ECS? Still hitting the same problem although I believe my deployment group has configured appropriate target groups, those are also registerd in load balancer.

Comment: @pbn that was quite a time... actually I switched to GCP, much better stuff 'n logs

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Maybe in next project :)

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still hitting this issue: in my case the ECS cluster had no outbound connectivity.

Possible solutions to this problem:

- make security groups you use with your VPC allow outbound traffic
- make sure that the route table you use with VPC has subnet associations with subnets you use with your load balancer (examine route tables)

I have able to figure it out because I enabled CloudWatch during ECS cluster creation and got `CannotPullContainerError`. For more information on solving this problem look into [Cannot Pull Container Image Error](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_cannot_pull_image.html).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Internet Gateway is attached to your Subnets through the Route Table (Routes), if your Load Balancer is internet facing.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to health check which detected an unhealthy target.
Make sure to check your configuration in Target group settings.[image]